# data-ajax-begin script in ASP.Net Core MVC blocks redirection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to create simple spinner in ASP.NET Core that will be shown while long lasting controller's action.

The code works as expected but it seems that it blocks redirection in controller's action. 
Is there any way to make the redirection work in this scenario?

My Index.cshtml

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/src/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onBegin() {
        $("#divLoading").html('<image src="~/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading, please wait" />');
    }
    function onComplete() {
        $("#divLoading").html("");
    }
</script>

<form data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="onBegin" data-ajax-complete="onComplete" asp-action="LoadLongLasting" asp-controller="Home">
    <input type="submit" value="Load Long lasting"/>
</form>
<div id="divLoading"></div>
```

Example of Controller's action:

```
    public ActionResult LoadLongLasting()
    {
        bool result = GetLongLastingResult();

        if(result)
        {
            return View();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Error");
    }
```

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page. Ajax calls never redirect so your `return RedirectToAction("Error");` is pointless

Comment: OK, so what would be the best practice to show an implemented spinner on begin of the request and hide at the end of it without Ajax. I believe that this is a quite common scenario, but to be honest I have no clue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return json and write redirect in onSuccess function like this.

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onBegin() {
        $("#divLoading").html('<image src="~/images/ajax-loader.gif"
alt="Loading, please wait" />');
    }
    function onSuccess() {
        if(data.status === 1) {
            window.location.href = "/yourpage";
        }
    }
    function onComplete() {
        $("#divLoading").html("");
    }
</script>

<form data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="onBegin" data-ajax-complete="onComplete" data-ajax-success="onSuccess" asp-action="LoadLongLasting" asp-controller="Home">
    <input type="submit" value="Load Long lasting"/>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult LoadLongLasting()
{
    bool result = GetLongLastingResult();

    if(result)
    {
        return View();
    }
    return Json(new { status = 1 });
    //return RedirectToAction("Error");
}
```